# sublime text2 python error message /usr/bin/python: can't find '__main__' module in ''

Tags: python

I installed sublime text 2 to OSX 10.8.2.
In my Mac, python 2.7.3 is installed.

In sublime text2, I just type

```
print 'Hello'
```

but error occurred like below.

```
/usr/bin/python: can't find '__main__' module in ''
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: just save the file first , and then run it

Answer (score 80):

I got the same error as I didn't save the script before executing it. Check to see if you have saved it!

Comment: [This looks like the explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50124994/4518341)

Answer (score 45):

Note to anyone else:

If you have a directory like so, you can add a `__main__.py` file to tell the interpreter what to execute if you call the module directly.

```
my_module
  |
  | __init__.py
  | my_cool_file.py # print "Hello  World"
  | __main__.py # import my_cool_file
```

`$ python my_module # Hello  World`

Answer (score 12):

You need to SAVE your code file with the ".py" extension. Then, on the 'Tools/Build System' menu, make sure your build system is set to either 'auto' or 'Python'. What that message is telling you is there is no valid Python file to 'build' (or, in this case just run).

Answer (score 4):

First save your program file type as "example.py then run your code its working fine.

Answer (score 2):

did you add the shebang to the top of the file?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't run with a space between the directory and the filename:

```
python /root/Desktop/1 hello.py
```

Use a `/` instead:

```
python /root/Desktop/1/hello.py
```

Comment: I'm not at all certain this addresses the problem actually experienced.

Comment: just try and see result

Comment: @GeorgeSariev I had this error, your suggestion just solved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem: The format of the file as to how it is saved.
Use a proper text editor and save it with the `.py` extension
and run it in terminal.

```
eg: file name should be saved as `example.py`
run
python example
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the .py files before you build in sublime.Such as save the file on desktop or other document.

Comment: This seems to be not different from the [highest voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14330557/8881141) Please post only answers that add a new aspect.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you aren't clicking on "Run unnamed" from 'run' tab. You must click on "run ". Or just click the green shortcut button.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the configuration and then in the box: Script path, select your .py file!

Answer (score -1):

You get that error because you haven't saved your file, save it for example "holamundo.py" then run it <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>