# IndentationError in python main files

Tags: python, sublimetext2

I am a newbie in python while I execute Hello World code on sublime text 2 I face this error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Python32\lib\runpy.py", line 142, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, loader, code, fname = _get_main_module_details()
  File "G:\Python32\lib\runpy.py", line 185, in _get_main_module_details
    return _get_module_details(main_name)
  File "G:\Python32\lib\runpy.py", line 114, in _get_module_details
    code = loader.get_code(mod_name)
  File "G:\Python32\lib\pkgutil.py", line 281, in get_code
    self.code = compile(source, self.filename, 'exec')
  File "G:\Python32\__main__.py", line 2
    |
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

Please help me

Comment: A copy of the code that produces the error would be nice

Comment: On line 2 of your program, the code indentation is wrong. Either you've indented to much or not enough. We'd have to see your code to see.

Comment: I had this problem /usr/bin/python: can't find 'main' module in '' [Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1] so I create __main__.py as someone said stackoverflow.com/a/17100701/2749197

Comment: @Ahmadsyr: You can't get further help unless you provide the code.

Comment: my code is just this
print("Hello World")

Comment: @Ahmadsyr: Delete any space at the beginning of that line.

Comment: There isn't actually any spaces but please see this __main__.py file I created (note that I have never edited it) http://stackoverflow.com/a/17100701/2749197

Comment: Ah there you go with such editors.... I use vim and never even heard of this :)

Comment: You should **definitely not** be trying to put your Python source code files into the folder where Python was installed.

Answer (score 3):

On line 2 of your program, the code indentation isn't correct.

Comment: I had this problem /usr/bin/python: can't find '__main__' module in ''
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
so I create __main__.py as someone said http://stackoverflow.com/a/17100701/2749197

Comment: That's a folder structure, not code. If you don't see, that this is no Python code please read the [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) and try to understand the language.

Answer (score 0):

indentation is Python’s way of grouping statements. At the interactive prompt, you have to type a tab or space(s) for each indented line.
When a compound statement is entered interactively, it must be followed by a blank line to indicate completion (since the parser cannot guess when you have typed the last line). Note that each line within a basic block must be indented by the same amount.