# sublime build system error "can't find '__main__' module in ''"

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext3

I'm trying to get Sublime3 to work with Python3.6.5 and getting an error message below.

```
/usr/bin/python: can't find '__main__' module in ''
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u ""]
[dir: /Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS]
[path:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

Answer (score 1):

This error is indicative of your not having saved your Python script file before you tried to run the build. In particular notice that in your posted output, you see the `shell_cmd` that was executed as:

```
[shell_cmd: python -u ""]
```

That is, it's trying to execute `python` with an empty file name. For example, compare that to the contents of your `sublime-build` file, which
probably looks something like:

```json
"shell_cmd": "python -u \"$file\"",
```

If the file is not saved, the file has no name, and as a result, the Python interpreter complains about the same thing:

```
/usr/bin/python: can't find '__main__' module in ''
```

The module name is an empty string (`''`), which should be the name of the file that you're trying to execute.

Comment: I did save it, but it doesn't end up in a list of Build System.

Comment: Your python files aren't going to show up in the list of build systems, only build systems will display there.

Comment: If you mean your build system isn't showing up in the list of build systems, that might be because the file is broken somehow. However, the fact that you got build output shows that something is building, so that doesn't seem to be your issue.

Comment: Correct, when I create new build system, I save it, and when i run Build on my script I get that error message.

Comment: Note that it's your Python script that needs to be saved to disk; the `python` command is external to Sublime; if the file isn't on disk, it can't see it.

Comment: Looks like that's the issue,  I never did save it.  I came from PyCharm and you don't have to save it to run the script

Comment: You only have to save the first time to initially create the file; once it's on disk as long as `Tools > Save all on build` is turned on, it will save automatically from that point forward.