# Cant run python in Sublime Text

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I have just installed sublime text and initially had issue with not having the Python3 build system. After referring to an answered question on the site I created a build system using the following code;

```
 {
    "cmd": ["/usr/bin/python3", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]File \"(...?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
 }
```

However after selecting the build system and attempting to run code I got the following error(what looks to be one at least)

```
/usr/bin/python3: can't find '__main__' module in ''
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['/usr/bin/python3', '-u', '']]
[dir: /app/extra/sublime_text]
[path: /app/utils/bin:/app/sublime_merge/bin:/app/bin:/usr/bin]
```

I'm not sure if I'm missing files. Nonetheless, thanks for your time, let me know if I haven't provided enough info or botched the sites format :).

Comment: Save your file to disk before you try to run it.. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50124994/814803

Comment: thanks a mil that worked great :D I assumed it auto saved it with the "untitled" title.

Comment: Once you save for the first time, having `Tools > Save all on build` checked (which it is by default) will make sure that your file is always saved to disk when you execute a build. It doesn't affect brand new files though.